# Xamarin Forms ListView ObservableCollection not updating

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms, observablecollection

I have a `ListView` that is bound to an `ObservableCollection` composed of `viewModels`.

the viewModel looks like this:

```
public string Id{ get; set; }
public string Name{ get; set; }
public bool HasId
{
    get { return !(String.IsNullOrEmpty(Id)); }
}
```

in the frontend xaml:

```
<ListView x:Name="MyList" ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}">
  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <ViewCell>
        <StackLayout>
          <Label Text="{Binding Name" FontSize="Small"/>
          <StackLayout Spacing="20">
            <Entry Text="{Binding Id}"/>
            <Button Text="Create Profile" IsEnabled="False">
              <Button.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger TargetType="Button" Binding="{Binding HasId}" Value="True">
                  <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
                </DataTrigger>
              </Button.Triggers>
            </Button>
          </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
      </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

**Desired Result**: when user types into entry (binded to `Id`), the button should be enabled.

**Actual Result**: when user types into entry, nothing happens (I'm guessing cause the `ObservableCollection` does not see the change within the `viewmodel`)

Note: When I add/delete an element to/from the `ObservableCollection`, the view does update (as expected).

Any suggestions/ideas are greatly appreciated!

Comment: your ViewModel class needs to implement INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: @Jason thanks! I didn't understand it the first time I read the documentation, but now it makes sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on the viewmodel class.

The `ObservableCollection<T>` class only handles notifications regarding whether the collection itself has changed - items added/removed/etc. It does not deal with notifications for when properties of the individual items themselves are changed.

Answer (score 0):

The Entry has a event name Called OnTextChanged (something like that, which you can use to enable the button, this can be done in Xaml or in code behind.

In regards of the listView not being refreshed have you tried to set "MyList" ObservableCollection again? which trigger the OnPropertyChanged Event of the View Model?