# Xamarin Forms Listview Not Updating GUI

Tags: listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, sendbird

I am trying to create a chatting page. There's a listview whose itemssource is an ObservableCollection. Everything seems to go smoothly until an item is added to the ObservableCollection. The added item does not immediately appear on the screen and only after touching the screen does it show up.

In fact, I have the same issue as stated here: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/18631/listview-binding-to-observablecollection-does-not-update-gui/p2

I believe one of the solutions stated in the thread (Page 2) has something to do with INotifyPropertyChanged. After many attempts of trying to apply the solution to fit my needs, I am unable to do so. So could you please guide me in the correct direction.

My code is **summarized** as follows:

```
public partial class Chat : ContentPage
{
    private ObservableCollection<MessageObj> Messages = new ObservableCollection<MessageObj>();

    public Chat(string name, string imageURL, int UID)
    {
        msgList.ItemsSource = Messages; //msgList is ListView in XAML
    }

    public class MessageObj
    {
        public string Mess { get; set; }
        public TextAlignment textAlignment { get; set; }

        public MessageObj(string Mess, TextAlignment textAlignment)
        {
            this.Mess = Mess;
            this.textAlignment = textAlignment;
        }
    }
}
```

I've also read: [Xamarin Forms ListView ObservableCollection not updating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37618209/xamarin-forms-listview-observablecollection-not-updating) I think I am changing the collection so I shouldn't be facing this issue but I am. 
Any help/insight would be greatly appreciated!

I have added a gist containing my code for reference which shows my now commented attempts at different solutions: https://gist.github.com/Dobermensch/49ee9d8adb9a83a38790b691c857691d

Edit: Added a little bit of more initially omitted code to gist

Edit2: FYI, I am not using the MVVM pattern.

Comment: MessageObj should be inhertied from `Bindable`

Comment: nowhere in that code do I see any attempt to add data to the Messages collection

Comment: I'm adding data in the Messages collection in OnAppearing(), in the function LoadChat()

Comment: Could you elaborate please 1SaeedSalehi? I cannot even think of what to google from that brief of a statement.

Comment: @ayudh change `public class MessageObj` to `public class MessageObj : Bindable` because BindableProperies needs to be monitored for changes or collection changes

Comment: Can i take a look at your ListView xaml?

Comment: You aren't using mvvm if you are writing your data code in your view's code behind. Binding is to be used when implementing the mvvm pattern, you need to go and research this.

Comment: Is the problem with the messages added during the OnAppearing call, during the OnMessageReceived callback, or both?

Comment: The ListView is provided in the Gist. I am not using the MVVM pattern. The problem is during the OnMessageReceived SendBird Channel Handler callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you clarified in comments, the problem is with the messages received during the OnMessageReceived callback from the SendBird API.  From reading their documentation, they do not appear to invoke the callback synchronously with the UI thread.

Xamarin applications can be multi-threaded, and there is one main, UI thread which *must* be involved in all updates to the UI.  In a lot of apps, the code you write will all run on the UI thread, unless you do things like `Task.Run()` or `await <some async task>.ConfigureAwait(false)` to force work off of the UI thread.  So normally you don't have to worry about UI vs non-UI threads.  Callbacks from user interaction with the UI, like button clicks, also run on the UI thread.  Callbacks from non-UI sources may or may not be on the UI thread (depending on implementation and luck), and I suspect that's the case here.

Depending on the platform you're working on, different things can go wrong if you attempt to change the UI from code that is not the UI thread.  Sometimes you get a crash (typical iOS response), or just won't update right away (common Android behavior).

So what I would try is to force the collection update to happen on the UI thread, using [Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/Xamarin.Forms.Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread?view=xamarin-forms), as such:

```
        ch.OnMessageReceived = (BaseChannel baseChannel, BaseMessage baseMessage) => {
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
            {
                Messages.Add(new MessageObj(((UserMessage)baseMessage).Message, TextAlignment.Start));
                msgList.ScrollTo(Messages.Last(), ScrollToPosition.End, false);
            };
        };
```

That will tell the UI thread to do the work of adding the MessageObj to Messages, so the various PropertyChanged events will also be handled on the UI thread, which will know how to actually update the UI.

Comment: I will give this a go when I get home. Fingers crossed!

Comment: @Ayudh Did that make a difference?

Comment: Long story: your answer didn't work with my existing code but it did work on my previous code which accomplishes the same objective. Therefore, as your suggestion has been instrumental in solving my issue, I'll accept it as an answer. I'll update my question with what works soon so you may have a look.

Answer (score 3):

I Had a similar issue, what I found, after a lot of debugging and testing is that GUI is not updating because of the `ItemsSource` of the `ListView` and **not** because of the `ObservableCollection`.

Setting the `ItemsSource` to null and then set it again with the `ObservableCollection` made the GUI to update.
although I was hoping for much more elegeant solution I could not find one.

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {
    Context.WarmupOptions[0].IsChecked = !Context.WarmupOptions[0].IsChecked;
    mylist.ItemsSource = null;
    mylist.ItemsSource = Context.WarmupOptions;
});
```